# how to find best possible path in a grid with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

[picture of map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zSj4.png)         I'm writing a code that makes its own grid filled with dots and 1's, 1 representing a lootable location and the dots representing a movable location. Every time the program moves one spot, the border closes in once. The program is supposed to figure out the best possible path that gives the most loot. I know I have to use recursion for this because that's the theme of the project but I'm unsure of how to fully go about it.

This is for java and I tried doing this to figure out every single path, but I dont know exactly how to find which one was the best one.

```
  public static int bestMoves(char[][] coordinates, int movesPossible, int playerX, int playerY, int mapSize, boolean[][] visited){
char[][] mapCopy = new char[mapSize][mapSize];
boolean[][] visitedCopy = new boolean[mapSize][mapSize];
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++){
    mapCopy[i][j] = coordinates[i][j];
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < mapSize; j++){
    visitedCopy[i][j] = visited[i][j];
  }
}

if (movesPossible > 0){
  if (playerX - 1 >=0  && !visited[playerY][playerX-1]){
    visitedCopy[playerX-1][playerY] = true;
    if (coordinates[playerY][playerX-1] == '1'){
      return 1 + bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX-1, playerY, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }else{
      return bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX-1, playerY, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }
  }

  if (playerY - 1 >=0  && !visited[playerY-1][playerX]){
    visitedCopy[playerY-1][playerX] = true;
    if (coordinates[playerY-1][playerX] == '1'){
      return 1 + bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX, playerY-1, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }else{
      return bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX, playerY-1, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }
  }

  else if (playerY + 1 >= mapSize  && !visited[playerY-1][playerX]){
    visitedCopy[playerY][playerX] = true;
    if (coordinates[playerY+1][playerX] == '1'){
      return 1 + bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX, playerY+1, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }else{
      return bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX, playerY+1, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }
  }

  else if (playerX + 1 >= mapSize  && !visited[playerY-1][playerX]){
    visitedCopy[playerY][playerX] = true;
    if (coordinates[playerY+1][playerX] == '1'){
      return 1 + bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX+1, playerY, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }else{
      return bestMoves(mapCopy, movesPossible-1, playerX+1, playerY, mapSize-1,visited); 
    }
  }else{
    return 0;
  }            
}else{
  return 0;
}
```

I call this function outside in the main, but it always just returns the number 1 instead of the best path. this is the map that is being used
1 . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 1 . .
. . . . 1 . . . . . .
. . 1 P . 1 1 1 . . .
. . 1 1 . . . . . . .
. . . 1 . . 1 . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . 1
. 1 1 1 . . . . . . .
. . 1 . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . 1 1 1
p is the original location

Comment: Is this question related to the _traveling salesman problem_?

Comment: somewhat, however in my program its about getting the most loot possible without getting out of the bounds, rather than getting the most loot in the least amount of time.

Comment: With _border closes in one spot_ you mean from each side, such that all outer points for that square cannot be used anymore?

Comment: yeah, so the border of the square becomes unused, and the player cannot move there (well the program but yeah).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that comes to my mind is related to the [MiniMax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm. In this algorithm, usually fitting for two player based zero-sum games, you create a game tree and evaluate possible positions up to a maximum depth. This can be adapted, of course, we have only one player here, so that the game tree can be created for each outgoing move (left, right, up, bottom, diagonal if needed) and evaluated with a function that scores better for each collected point. If no more points are left on the board, no more outgoing positions are created. AT the end, take that path that scored the most points.

If the depth is good enough, this should always lead to a best-effort-solution.

Of course, if the board gets larger, there may be a better algorithm. But since the board is shrinking rapidly each move, all positions should be able to be generated.

Comment: how could i implement it into my situation?

Comment: what i was thinking right now was using recursion(as we are supposed to) and make whatever position they are at go up, down, left, and right. and then all of those possibilities also go up, down, left, and right unless they already visited that location and so on.

Comment: Yeah, this is mostly the same what i did come up with. You pass each possible board via recursion to the method and keep track of collected points. Remember to shrink the board passed to the next method call.